# How to mock DateFormat.is24HourFormat() for unit tests in Android?

Tags: android, mocking, date-format, robolectric

In my code, I check for time format of the system in android

```
....
....
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)
....
....
```

my question is how can I mock result of this method for the unit test?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `robolectric` library for mocking this value. Tested on version `4.3`.

```
org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSettings.set24HourTimeFormat(false)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for us. Adding some keywords so it can be more easily found: Setup Robolectric 12 hour/24 hour formatting option for DateFormat.is24HourFormat.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MockK:

```
    mockkStatic(DateFormat::class)
    every { DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context) } returns false
```

*Extra info: The reason I didn't use `mockk()` instead of the `context` for `is24HourFormat` is that my class which has this DateFormat code also needs context, so I mocked the context like:*

```
@MockK
private lateinit var context: Context
```

*and used it for both creating an instance of my class and for mocking `is24HourFormat`. Using different mocked contexts didn't work.*